# Type Script function to scroll to specific table index

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mat-table

I need help to write a function in type script,so that i can scroll to specific index in material table.

Lets say i have 100 rows in my table showing 10 items at a time. If i provide input as 50, table should be scrolled upto row no. 50.

I am using type script with my angular html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all rows of table as array and then scroll to specific row by using index

```
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-row cdk-row");
rows[50].scrollIntoView();
```

Or you can use query selector

```
document.querySelectorAll(".custom-table .mat-row");
```

Here custom-table is your table custom class name. This way you can get specific table rows if you have multiple tables on a page

Comment: Thanks for the response zain. I did as you suggested. I am able to fetch rows. I can see in console logs. But its not scrolling. I have 3 tables on the page, does that has an impact ?

Comment: Yes it can be an issue. You can confirm with rows array length if it is equal to table rows or not

Comment: Rows look like below in console logs:
HTMLCollection(2) [mat-row.mat-row.cdk-row.cdk-drag.ng-star-inserted, mat-row.mat-row.cdk-row.cdk-drag.ng-star-inserted]

Comment: all tables will have same length. Can it be distinguished based on table id or something?

Comment: That shows that you only have two rows. You have to share code for further details